# Servlet Mappings with Variables(Tomcat 7.0)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

Is it possible to map URLs to servlets (maybe something specific with Tomcat) so that the two following URLs (with {id}'s being variables retrievable from code),

```
/users/{id}/a

/users/{id}/b
```

map to two different servlets, or will I have to implement some sort of filter of my own for a servlet mapped to `/users/*`?

To be more clear, any URL with the pattern `/users/*/a` should map to the same servlet. The same goes for `/users/*/b`.

Comment: You want to map two different ids to two different servlets..?

Comment: To be more clear, any URL with the pattern /users/*/a should map to the same servlet. The same goes for /users/*/b.

Comment: Can you post the exact  url rather than putting id.?

Comment: `PathVariable`s are the most glaring missing feature of Servlet 3.0 API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could map it on `/users/*` and extract information from [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29):

```
@WebServlet("/users/*")
public class UsersController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String[] pathInfo = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
        String id = pathInfo[1]; // {id}
        String command = pathInfo[2]; // a or b
        // ...
    }

}
```

*(obvious validation on array size omitted)*

Answer (score 6):

This looks like it might be a good candidate for [JAX-RS](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311). I'm not sure what business logic your servlets currently perform, but this option addresses your servlet mapping question and may be appropriate.

```
@Path("/users/{id}")
public class User { 

    @Path("a")
    public String doA(@PathParam("id") final int id) { ... }

    @Path("b")
    public String doB(@PathParam("id") final int id) { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. Either use the [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) or some framework like Spring-MVC that is capable of mapping more complex URLs