# Servlet and path parameters like /xyz/{value}/test, how to map in web.xml?

Tags: servlets, get, web.xml, path-parameter

Does servlet support urls as follows:

```
/xyz/{value}/test
```

where value could be replaced by text or number.

How to map that in the web.xml?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252442/servlet-mappings-with-variablestomcat-7-0 (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your best bet is the URL pattern `/xyz/*`.

The [Servlet API](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-6.0) doesn't support to have the URL pattern wildcard `*` in the middle of the mapping such as `/xyz/*/test` nor URI templates. It only [allows](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-6.0#specification-of-mappings) the wildcard `*` in the end of the mapping like so `/prefix/*` or in the start of the mapping like so `*.suffix`.

You can extract the path information using [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getPathInfo()). Here's a basic kickoff example how to extract the path information, null and array index out of bounds checks omitted for brevity:

```java
@WebServlet("/xyz/*")
public class XyzServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); // /{value}/test
        String[] pathParts = pathInfo.split("/");
        String value = pathParts[1]; // {value}
        String action = pathParts[2]; // test
        
        if ("test".equals(action)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to use [URI templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_Template) nonetheless, and this is actually intended to be a REST endpoint rather than a HTML page, then take a look at [Jakarta REST (JAX-RS)](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#extracting-path-parameters):

```java
@Path("/xyz/{value}/test")
public class XyzResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getTest(@PathParam("value") String value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want more finer grained control liks as possible with Apache HTTPD's `mod_rewrite`, then you could look at [Tuckey's URL rewrite filter](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) or [homegrow your own URL rewrite filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url).

Comment: Is this really *the way* one needs to extract url parameters which are not GET-parameters? This seems quite bloated, hard to maintain, prone to offset-bugs and 1995 in general.

Comment: @Herbert: just use a framework on top of Servlet API which supports path parameters, such as JAX-RS or MVC.

Comment: Another option is getRequestURI(), in my case getPathInfo() was empty.

Comment: @leventunver: it will be empty in a filter, or when a badly implemented request wrapper is being used somewhere in the request, or due to a bug in the servletcontainer.

Comment: I modified a class that extends GenericFilterBean. Uses ServletRequest as input.

Comment: @leventunver: well, a filter is clearly not a servlet.

Answer (score 10):

As others have indicated, the servlet specification does not allow such patterns; however, you might consider [JAX-RS](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) which does allow such patterns, if this is appropriate for your use case.

```
@Path("/xyz/{value}/test")
public class User { 

    public String doSomething(@PathParam("value") final String value) { ... }

}
```

Or:

```
@Path("/xyz/{value}")
public class User { 

    @Path("test")
    public String doTest(@PathParam("value") final String value) { ... }

}
```

(Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303767/843093.)

Answer (score 3):

It does support mapping that url; but doesn't offer any validation.

In your web xml, you could do this....

```
/xyz/*
```

But that won't guarantee that the trailing `test` is present and that it is the last item.  If you're looking for something more sophisticated, you should try urlrewritefilter.

http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing that in web.xml rather you can point every request to your filter (Patternfilter) and can check for URL

```
package com.inventwheel.filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class PatternFilter
 */
@WebFilter("/*")
public class PatternFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public PatternFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String servletPath = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getServletPath();
            String requestURI = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*"+servletPath+"/(.*)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(requestURI);
            if (matcher.matches())
            {
            String param = matcher.group(1);
            // do stuff with param here..
            }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

No Servlet doesn't support patterns like that, possible approach as mentioned by other folks as well is to use `/*` after `xyz` but that doesn't check for `{value}` or `/test`. Better you go for Spring or JAX-RS. However if you plan to stick with Servlet a better way to write it:

`@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/xyz/*"})`

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, base servlets does not support patterns like you specified in your question.  Spring MVC does support patterns.  [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex) is a link to the pertinent section in the [Spring Reference Document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

Answer (score 0):

An answer from the year 2022.

1. Servlets do still not allow wildcards, so we can't do things like:
   `/xyz/{value}/test`
2. Paul Tuckeys *urlrewritefilter* is still in version 4.0.3, and not compatible with the new jakarta namespace [1] (Version 5 is in development).

I found a solution in Tomcat itself, with its feature *RewriteValve*. 
See https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/tomcat-rewrite-url for a step-by-step manual. This is a convenient solution for allowing wildcards in the middle of a URL.

[1] https://github.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/issues/239