# Wildcard path for servlet?

Tags: servlets, wildcard, url-pattern, path-parameter

Having an `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/myServlet/")`. If the user goes to `myapp/myServlet/other`, I still want my servlet to catch. So to say, wildcard anything on after the servlet path. How could I do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `*` as prefix or suffix wildcard. In your case, you can use `/myServlet/*` for a folder mapping.

```
@WebServlet("/myServlet/*")
```

The path info (the part after the mapping in the URL) is in the servlet by the way available as:

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
```

This would in case of `myapp/myServlet/other` return `/other`.

#### See also:

- [Servlet and path parameters like /xyz/{value}/test, how to map in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715474/servlet-and-path-parameters-like-xyz-value-test-how-to-map-in-web-xml/)

Comment: Wow thats incredibly nice! I just tried the * wildcard with urlPatterns, which did not work. But this does as expected.

Comment: By the way you just answered my next question (how to get the path) :)

Answer (score 0):

use "/myServlet/*" as your servlet mapping.