# Liferay - Can't get value from the URL on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, param

I'm having issue in fetching the value from the url eg:`xyz.com/customer/1001`. Here 1001 is the customer Id and I'm using the following command to get the value on the jsp :

```
long customerId = Long.valueOf(ParamUtil.getString(request,"customerId"));
```

Using the above code it gives me null as the value of customerId even though it is present in the url.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From your URL, where does it say `1001` is `customerId`? And you are extracting it from GET request with the name of `customerId`. You are using Django pattern, you could see [***this***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715474/servlet-and-path-parameters-like-xyz-value-test-how-to-map-in-web-xml#answer-8715566)

Answer (score 3):

`ParamUtil.getString` method have two arguments `getString(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, String param)` as you can see the second argument is "param". To get value of this parameter, the url  have to contains this parameter so you can try to access this url `xyz.com/customer?customerId=1001`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the old projects in tomcat webapps, when I deleted it now it's working.

thanks anyway